# How do I check if a variable holds a valid Element within a Google Drive document?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Something like the following is a necessary feature:

```
function doFoo(element) {
  if (!isValidElement(element))
    throw new Error("doFoo: not a valid element");
  // do some stuff
}
```

I've now tried the following to no avail:

```
function test() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var element = body.appendHorizontalRule();
  Logger.log(doc.contains(element));
  Logger.log(body.contains(element));
}
```